# How to determine binding type for items in a sap.m.Select?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

When using a sap.m.Input, I can configure the element like in the example below, in order to set the type of the item that is binded to the Input:

```
<mvc:View>
     <Input value="{ 
         path:'/company/revenue', 
         type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Float'
     }"/>
</mvc:View>
```

this way, when I retrieve the property inside '/company/revenue', its type will always be a JavaScript number. However, is it possible to apply a similar "typing" to a sap.m.Select? The property "selectedKey" inside a sap.m.Select always returns a JavaScript String, but I would like to type it to a number like I did with the sap.m.Input above. How can I do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would guess that a "key" has to be a String by definition. All methods in `sap.m.Select` that are connected to the key either expect or receive a String. You can cast the String to a number on your own, but I don't think you can force the `Select` control to accept numerical datatypes as key.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that. It's just a normal property binding.

But beware that the keys of your items inside the `Select` control have to be compatible with the Float type. The `sap.ui.model.type.Float` without any formatOptions generates locale dependant strings. So in germany f.e. you get a `,` as decimal separator and in the US it would be `.`.

A good idea would be to use a aggregation binding to create the items and configure the keys of the items with the same type as the selectedKey property of your select. See example on [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/qunayuyaqe/edit?html,js,output).

```xml
  <Select 
     selectedKey="{path:'/selectedKey',type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Float'}"
     items="{/items}">
    <c:ListItem 
      key="{path: 'key', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Float'}" 
      text="{text}"/>
  </Select>
```

```js
onInit:function(){
  var data = {
    selectedKey:3,
    items: [
      { key: -1, text: "Item 1" },
      { key: 1.234, text: "Item 2" },
      { key: 3, text: "Item 3" },
      { key: 1234, text: "Item 4" }
    ]
  };
  var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(data);
  this.getView().setModel(model);
}
```